# Маскировка Google Chrome на Windows под мобильный браузер (андроид)

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите, есть ли возможность замаскировать полностью Google Chrome на Windows под мобильный браузер так, чтобы удаленный сервер определил мою ОС как андроид?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам использую консоль разработчика и UA swithcer
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По UAswitcher написал выше, консоль разработчика наверное тоже не позволит скрыть ОС.

Comment: Всё позволяет.
https://i86.fastpic.ru/big/2019/1021/19/6513421a1e5fdc97d621954df9b49f19.jpg

Comment: Надо протестить тогда, отпишусь позже, что получилось.

Comment: Сработало, еще бы на селениуме это выставить, но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам надо что-то типа вот этого: https://winaero.com/blog/change-user-agent-chrome/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Похоже данное решение не позволяет скрыть операционную систему клиента : "Please note that this does not provide improved privacy while browsing the Internet and that some sites might have other means to figure out that the browser is not what it pretends to be"

Comment: @Lex А если заблокировать выполнение JavaScript на сайте?

Comment: @Генадий П пробовал, но не на всех сайтах работает. Находил вариант с программой Multilogin. Но хотелось бы использовать Chrome.

Comment: Может вот это сможет помочь: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-online-emulator/lnhnebkkgjmlgomfkkmkoaefbknopmja

Comment: @balamutik, спасибо за ответ! Попробую протестировать.